# Why isn't there a "transaction" method in Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, mongoid

Some times we want to save some objects not directly related with each other. Failures may occur on one or several of them. If there isn't a "transaction" strategy, how can we save all or none?

Answer (score 4):

Because Mongodb doesnt support transactions. MongoDB provides atomicity for an operation on a single document. Check out why [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-transactions) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that into Mongoid, but if there's no such thing as a transaction, you could probably just check if any of the objects is not `#valid?` and if so, just don't save all objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If this is a hard requirement you'll either have to embed the related objects into eachother so they can be modified using atomic updates or you will need to find another persistence solution. MongoDB does a lot of things well, but transactions is not one of those things.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 3.6, MongoDB provide `session`

```
s = Mongoid.client(:default).start_session
s.start_transaction
s.commit_transaction
```

Details about Session class can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Session/)

Answer (score 1):

From MongoDB 4.0 ([manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0/#multi-document-transactions)), multi-document transactions are supported in replica sets

From MongoDB 4.2 ([manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2/#distributed-transactions)), multi-document transactions are available in sharded clusters

But transactions are slow, and should be avoided if performance is the main concern (cf denormalized fields)